# CanFestival readNetworkDict() fails

Tags: embedded, canopen

I'm trying to bring up CAN bus client application based on CanFestival.

When I try to read from the CAN server readNetworkDict() fails in the following code

```
    offset = d->firstIndex->SDO_CLT;
    lastIndex = d->lastIndex->SDO_CLT;
    if (offset == 0) {
        MSG_ERR(0x1AC6, "No SDO client index found for nodeId ", nodeId);
        return 0xFF;
    }
```

and this is SDO_CLT in my dictionary.

```
const quick_index GoldTwitter_firstIndex = {
  3, /* SDO_SVR */
  0, /* SDO_CLT */
  4, /* PDO_RCV */
  5, /* PDO_RCV_MAP */
  6, /* PDO_TRS */
  7 /* PDO_TRS_MAP */
};
```

Having only a couple of days of CAN bus experience I have some basic questions.

What is SDO_CLT?

Is it being zero indicates the problem in dictionary generation or I have to initialize it during runtime?

Comment: "Having only a couple of days of CAN bus experience"  What makes you think that you are competent enough to write a CANopen application then...? I would guess that this error is related to your client not understanding which SDO to use to ping the object dictionary of other nodes in the network. Possibly it has not been configured. Is the error reported for your node or the node you are trying to communicate with? I have no experience of this particular CANopen stack.

Comment: SDO clients are "contexts" used to perform SDO operations. You typically define them statically in the object dictionary (as  shown by @JMA answer) or dynamically by writing the same info using `writeLocalDict()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the SDO parameters in the dictionary, something like this:
[image]